# ASP.NET .aspx page: how to send extra data back via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an old-fashioned ASP.NET plain .aspx page.
It has some server-side controls, some buttons to postback, etc.

I'm going to add some Javascript on the client side to create a list of extra data that the user builds.
I don't know beforehand how much of this extra data will be sent. So I can't, for example, just add 10 hidden input fields and check their values in the codebehind.

There might be 20 values sent back, there might be 100.

What's the best way to POST this extra data back to the server?

One way I can imagine it working is to add some dummy hidden list controls, to be filled in by JS on the client. It feels hacky, but I think I could make it work.

**Is there a better way?**

Some things to note:

- I'm not using MVC or AJAX
- Not using JQuery (though I could, I suppose)

I'm really just trying to get a handle on my options.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a single hidden field but join the data with a separator like a;b;c;d or a|b|c|d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't need to be POSTed via ajax you can use javascript to create the controls and then use Request.Form to retrieve the input values.

ASPX:

```
<script>
    document.write('<input name="field1" type="text" />' + 
                   '<input name="field2" type="text" />');
</script>

<asp:Button ID="btn" Text="button" runat="server" onclick="btn_Click" />
```

ASPX.CS:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var keys = Request.Form.AllKeys;
    foreach (var key in keys)
    {
        if (key.StartsWith("field"))
            Response.Write(Request.Form[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I have been using controls so long I forgot you can just get all the data directly via `Request.Form`.